# Groovy grapes freeze after downloading artifacts

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

After updating my ubuntu system I have problem to run groovy grapes scripts. All dependecies are download but process is still running in about 100 %

I have ubuntu :

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

groovy version:

```
Groovy Version: 1.8.6 JVM: 1.7.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

My simple script look like:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6')
@GrabExclude('asm:*')

import groovyx.net.http.*
import groovy.util.CliBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class MyGroovyScript {

static main(args) {
    println "?????"
} 

}
```

and output is:

```
groovy -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true my-groovy-script.groovy
Resolving dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.6 {default=[default]}
Preparing to download artifact org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.6!http-builder.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3!json-lib.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;1.8.8!groovy.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16!nekohtml.jar
Preparing to download artifact xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2!xml-resolver.jar
Preparing to download artifact org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1!httpcore.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1!commons-collections.jar
Preparing to download artifact commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar
Preparing to download artifact net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6!ezmorph.jar
Preparing to download artifact antlr#antlr;2.7.7!antlr.jar
Preparing to download artifact xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1!xercesImpl.jar
Preparing to download artifact xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04!xml-apis.jar
Downloaded 9854 Kbytes in 134ms:
  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.6!http-builder.jar (5ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar (7ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1!httpcore.jar (2ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar (1ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar (2ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.sf.json-lib#json-lib;2.3!json-lib.jar (2ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar (3ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1!commons-collections.jar (5ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar (2ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.sf.ezmorph#ezmorph;1.0.6!ezmorph.jar (24ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.codehaus.groovy#groovy;1.8.8!groovy.jar (34ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] antlr#antlr;2.7.7!antlr.jar (5ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.16!nekohtml.jar (2ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] xerces#xercesImpl;2.9.1!xercesImpl.jar (14ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] xml-apis#xml-apis;1.3.04!xml-apis.jar (3ms)
  [SUCCESSFUL ] xml-resolver#xml-resolver;1.2!xml-resolver.jar (2ms)
```

Comment: This was on the [mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Use-Grab-the-program-looks-like-be-blocked-td5716633.html) only 2 days ago.  I assume you're using OpenJDK update 25? They changed they way an integral function worked, so Grab has stopped working with that version of Java

Comment: yes this is exactly my problem. thx a lot. Btw did you think it will be fixed in new update of java

Comment: I believe they have said that the code will be changed back (in Java 7), but no word as to what will happen in Java 8, or whether this fix is permanent :-( http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Grab-and-Java-8-td5716099.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no answer posted yet.. This happens because of OpenJDK7u25 and it works again with u40